# Scala transform and split String Column to MapType Column in Dataframe

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark

I have a DataFrame with a column, containing tracking request urls with fields inside, that looks like this

```
df.show(truncate = false)
+--------------------------------
| request_uri
+-----------------------------------
| /i?aid=fptplay&ast=1582163970763&av=4.6.1&did=83295772a8fee349 ...
| /i?p=fplay-ottbox-2019&av=2.0.18&nt=wifi&ov=9&tv=1.0.0&tz=GMT%2B07%3A00 ...
| ...
```

I need to transform this column to something that looks like this

```
df.show(truncate = false)
+--------------------------------
| request_uri
+--------------------------------
| (aid -> fptplay, ast -> 1582163970763, tz -> [timezone datatype], nt -> wifi , ...) 
| (p -> fplay-ottbox-2019, av -> 2.0.18, ov -> 9, tv -> 1.0.0 , ...) 
| ...
```

Basically I have to split the field names (delimiter = "&" ) and their values into a MapType of some sort, and add that to the column.

Can someone give me pointers how to write a custom function to split the string column into a MapType column?
I'm told to use withColumn() and mapPartition but I don't know how to implement it in a way that will split the strings and cast them to MapType.

Any help even though minimal would be heartily appreciated. I'm completely new to Scala and have been stuck on this for a week.

Comment: Maybe you could look into Spark User-Defined Functions (UDFs). https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-spark-sql/content/spark-sql-udfs.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use [UserDefinedFunctions](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-functions-udf-scalar.html).

Let's take the problem one step at a time.

```scala
// We need a function which converts strings into maps
// based on the format of request uris
def requestUriToMap(s: String): Map[String, String] = {
  s.stripPrefix("/i?").split("&").map(elem => {
    val pair = elem.split("=")     
    (pair(0), pair(1)) // evaluate each element to a tuple
  }).toMap
}

// Now we convert this function into a UserDefinedFunction.
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{col, udf}
// Given to a request uri string, convert it to map, the correct format is assumed.
val requestUriToMapUdf = udf((requestUri: String) => requestUriToMap(requestUri))
```

Now, we test.

```scala
// Test data
val df = Seq(
  ("/i?aid=fptplay&ast=1582163970763&av=4.6.1&did=83295772a8fee349"),
  ("/i?p=fplay-ottbox-2019&av=2.0.18&nt=wifi&ov=9&tv=1.0.0&tz=GMT%2B07%3A00")
).toDF("request_uri")

df.show(false)
//+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
//|request_uri                                                            |
//+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
//|/i?aid=fptplay&ast=1582163970763&av=4.6.1&did=83295772a8fee349         |
//|/i?p=fplay-ottbox-2019&av=2.0.18&nt=wifi&ov=9&tv=1.0.0&tz=GMT%2B07%3A00|
//+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+

// Now we execute our UDF to create a column, using the same name replaces that column
val mappedDf = df.withColumn("request_uri", requestUriToMapUdf(col("request_uri")))
mappedDf.show(false)
//+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
//|request_uri                                                                                  |
//+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
//|[aid -> fptplay, ast -> 1582163970763, av -> 4.6.1, did -> 83295772a8fee349]                 |
//|[av -> 2.0.18, ov -> 9, tz -> GMT%2B07%3A00, tv -> 1.0.0, p -> fplay-ottbox-2019, nt -> wifi]|
//+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

mappedDf.printSchema
//root
// |-- request_uri: map (nullable = true)
// |    |-- key: string
// |    |-- value: string (valueContainsNull = true)

mappedDf.schema
//org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType = StructType(StructField(request_uri,MapType(StringType,StringType,true),true))
```

And that's what you wanted.

---

Alternative: If you're not sure if your string conforms, you can try a different variation of the function which succeeds even if the string doesn't conform to assumed format (doesn't contain `=` or input is an empty String).

```scala
def requestUriToMapImproved(s: String): Map[String, String] = {
  s.stripPrefix("/i?").split("&").map(elem => {
    val pair = elem.split("=")
    pair.length match {
      case 0 => ("", "") // in case the given string produces an array with no elements e.g. "=".split("=") == Array() 
      case 1 => (pair(0), "") // in case the given string contains no = and produces a single element e.g. "potato".split("=") == Array("potato")
      case _ => (pair(0), pair(1)) // normal case e.g. "potato=masher".split("=") == Array("potato", "masher")
    }
  }).toMap
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this code snippet worked perfectly. but when I swapped your Seq df with my original df, it threw ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException at the line "(pair(0), pair(1))". I don't get why.

Comment: @VũJean, it means that one of the strings between `&`s doen't have a `=` in the body of the text, so the split we do simply returns the string as is in an array, so the array doesn't have a second element. `"potato".split("=")` => `Array(potato)` which has one element. So the question is, what should happen to those kind of strings?

Comment: The string could also be totally empty. Make sure to filter out empty records.

Comment: I just added a function which handles the case of non-conforming strings. So it will produce a `"key" -> ""` if the string doesn't contain an `=` or a `"" -> ""` if the given string is empty.

Answer (score 0):

The following code performs a two phase split process. Because uris don´t have an specific structure you can do it with an UDF like:

```
val keys = List("aid", "p", "ast", "av", "did", "nt", "ov", "tv", "tz")

def convertToMap(keys: List[String]) = udf  {
  (in : mutable.WrappedArray[String]) =>
    in.foldLeft[Map[String, String]](Map()){ (a, str) =>
      keys.flatMap { key =>
        val regex = s"""${key}="""
        val arr = str.split(regex)
        val value = {
          if(arr.length == 2) arr(1)
            else ""
        }

        if(!value.isEmpty)
          a + (key -> value)
        else
          a
      }.toMap
    }
}

df.withColumn("_tmp",
  split($"request_uri","""((&)|(\?))"""))
  .withColumn("map_result", convertToMap(keys)($"_tmp"))
  .select($"map_result")
  .show(false)
```

it gives a MapType column:

```
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|map_result                                                                                      |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|Map(aid -> fptplay, ast -> 1582163970763, av -> 4.6.1, did -> 83295772a8fee349)                 |
|Map(av -> 2.0.18, ov -> 9, tz -> GMT%2B07%3A00, tv -> 1.0.0, p -> fplay-ottbox-2019, nt -> wifi)|
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```